# No colour attachment in metal render pass

Tags: metal

Is it possible to have an `MTLRenderPassDescriptor` that renders to a depth or stencil texture, but has no colour attachments? Like so:

```
MTLRenderPassDescriptor* textureRenderPassDescriptor = [MTLRenderPassDescriptor renderPassDescriptor];
MTLRenderPassStencilAttachmentDescriptor* textureAttachment = [[MTLRenderPassStencilAttachmentDescriptor alloc]init];
textureAttachment.texture = texture;
textureAttachment.loadAction = MTLLoadActionClear;
textureAttachment.storeAction = MTLStoreActionStore;
textureRenderPassDescriptor.stencilAttachment = textureAttachment;
```

I tried doing that, but got the following error when trying to use this pipeline state:

```
failed assertion `For color attachment 0, the renderPipelineState pixelFormat must be MTLPixelFormatInvalid, as no texture is set.'
```

Answer (score 3):

As the assertion states, you need to set `pixelFormat` to invalid when creating a `MTLRenderPipelineState`:

```
pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = MTLPixelFormatInvalid;
```